# Convert a datatable to a data structure to be read by MS stacked chart control?

Tags: vb.net, charts, webchartcontrol

I have a chart control (stacked chart to be more precise) and a datatable that contains 3 columns. I want to bind them into a stacked bar chart. below is what the datatable looks like:

**Resource      |          Queue         |       Hoursworked**

Billy Jones | Projects - Internal | 234

Billy Jones | Tier 1 Support  | 234

Alan Clark | Projects - Internal | 123

Alan Clark | Tier 1 Support  | 234

I would have the Resource column as the x-axis, and the value (hours worked) of each Queue as the y-axis (stacked)

Can anyone help? I've tried just binding normally and I'm getting an error saying that it's the wrong data type.

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out for size:

```
DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
table2.Columns.Add("Resource", typeof(string));
table2.Columns.Add("Queue", typeof(string));
table2.Columns.Add("Hoursworked", typeof(int));

table2.Rows.Add("Billy Jones", "Projects - Internal", 234);
table2.Rows.Add("Billy Jones", "Tier 1 Support" ,  234);
table2.Rows.Add("Alan Clark", "Projects - Internal" ,123);
table2.Rows.Add("Alan Clark", "Tier 1 Support", 234);

foreach (DataRow row in table2.Rows)
{
   string seriesName1 = row["Queue"].ToString();
   Series series = new Series(); ;
   try {
      series = Chart2.Series[seriesName1];
   }
   catch {
      if (series.Name == "") {
         Chart2.Series.Add(seriesName1);
         Chart2.Series[seriesName1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
      }
   }
   Chart2.Series[row["Queue"].ToString()].Points.AddXY(row["Resource"].ToString(), (int)row["Hoursworked"]);
}
```